# Autofac Named/Keyed резолвинг и вложенные зависимости

Tags: c#, autofac

При попытке сделать резолвинг по имени вылетает ошибка 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'ConsoleApplication1.Program+MainClassOlolo' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'INamed named' of constructor 'Void .ctor(INamed)'."

**При резолвинге Named/Keyed вложенные зависимости также будут резолвиться с использованием Name/Key или же это распространяется непосредственно на сам класс, который резолвится?**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new ContainerBuilder();
            container.RegisterType<NamedB>().Named<INamed>("B");
            container.RegisterType<NamedA>().Named<INamed>("A");
            container.RegisterType<MainClassOne>().Named<MainClassOne>("A");
            container.RegisterType<MainClassTwo>().Named<MainClassTwo>("B");

            var di = container.Build();
            var a = di.ResolveNamed<MainClassTwo>("B");
            var a2 = di.ResolveNamed<MainClassOne>("A");

        }

        public class MainClassOne
        {
            public MainClassOne(INamed named)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MainClassBla = " + named.Name);
            }
        }

        public class MainClassTwo
        {
            public MainClassTwo(INamed named)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MainClassOlolo = " + named.Name);
            }
        }

        public interface INamed
        {
           string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class NamedA : INamed
        {
            public string Name
            {
                get { return "A"; }
                set { }
            }
        }

        public class NamedB : INamed
        {
            public string Name
            {
                get { return "B"; }
                set { }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710779/autofac-resolve-a-specific-dependency-to-a-named-instance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040577/autofac-naming-resolving-and-child-dependencies